# Facebook sharing preview dialog image is different from shared image

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I'm trying to share a page on Facebook with the following button:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button" data-href="http://myPageURLHere"></div>
```

In the meta tags I added the following to let Facebook take a specific image for the sharing:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://myLinkToThe/Image.jpg">
```

When I click on the button the image in the share dialog is not `Image.jpg` but a different one, but if I share the page the resulting post on Facebook contains `Image.jpg` as image correctly

I analyzed the page here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
and everything seems ok but the image in the preview

Any ideas on why this behavior is occuring?

Comment: Likely just a simple caching issue.

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't know why but only today the debugger is taking all data correctly and giving me a warning related to the image dimensions. Yesterday was everything ok.

Comment: Does seem like a caching issue. The best thing to do is to just click the "Fetch new Scrape" information and it should solve the issue for you.